# Equivalent between axiom of choice and existence of non-measure sets?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

It can be shown that axioms of choice allows us to construct non-measurable sets but can I say the converse i.e. $ZF +  non \; measure \; sets \; exist$ contains $ZFC$.

Comment: I don’t think so, although someone more qualified can answer. This is because I know you don’t quite need the full axiom of choice to get non-measurable sets, there are some slightly weaker conditions (almost choice) that give you non measurable sets.

Comment: @Bagggggggs That's right. If you know it's consistent that ZF + not AC + there are non-measurable sets, then you know that ZF + there are non-measurable sets does not imply AC.